# How to put elements under each other with a ListView?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having a hard time to put items under each other when a ListView is involved.

I've this code :

```
body:
    Column(
        children: [
            Text('foo'),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    controller:     ...,
                    itemCount:      ...,
                    itemBuilder:    ... 
                )
            ),
            Text('bar')
        ]
    )
,
```

It gives me the result on the left, but I'd like the one on the right :

[image: Layouts]

I tried to put the ListView in a Container (with an `height: double.maxFinite`) but its give me an : `Bottom overflowed by X pixels`.

***Edit*** : Here is the result I'm trying to achieve (run the snippet in "full page") :

```css
body {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mobile {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid cyan;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-top: 41px;
}

.appbar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 10px;
}

.list-view {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile">
  <div class="appbar">AppBar</div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
  <div class="list-view">ListView</div>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a CustomScrollView

```
CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Text("Text"),
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate( [
              Container(
                height: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.pink),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 500.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
              )
            ]),
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Text("Text"),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Notice you can use a SliverChildListDelegate or a SliverChildBuilderDelegate

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`body:
    Column(
        children: [
            Text('foo'),
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: .......,
                    itemCount: .....,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            Text('bar')
        ]
    )
,`

This code worked for me.

Comment: No, same result as my left image.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the top and bottom foo and bar as the first and last items of the list. The `ListView` will have `list.length + 2` items.

```
  body: Column(children: [
    Text('foo'),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: list.length + 2,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == 0)
            return Text("foo");
          else if (index < list.length + 1)
            return Text("$index");
          else
            return Text('bar');
        },
      ),
    ),
  ]),
```

Comment: I edited my post with an example in HTML/CSS. With your solution, my 'foo' will always be fixed at the top of my body.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include "foo" as the first item of the list.

Comment: Anyway, the answer that uses `Slivers` should be the way to go.